# How to work with a custom layer on top of Google map in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a android app which is using Location based services. I can integrate the google map in to my app. But I want to locate the lat and long points on a layer on top of the google map. So is there anyone who can help me with this???

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: I can integrate the google map in to  my app. But what i want is to work on a layer on top of the google map. To locate the lat and long locations on the layer which is on top of the google map.